# Can a synonym be made for the [windows-phone] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

The tag [windows-phone-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7) should be retagged [windows-phone](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone). While there are a few more instances including the `7` bit, the questions listed all apply to every current version of Windows Phone, including the planned release, "Mango".

Therefore, the tag should refer generally to the platform, rather than a single specific instance of the OS.

However, I lack the reputation in either tag to make the suggestion. :(

Can someone do that?

Answer (score 2):

I agree, the other mobile operating systems are setup in a similar way...

```
updating post history, 37 rows affected
updating posts, 28 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 28 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
merge of [windows-phone] and [windows-phone-7] complete!
Tag Synonym windows-phone-7 -> windows-phone was approved!
```